# Is it possible to travel from Ireland to England on a student visa

Tags: visas, uk, ireland, england

I would be traveling to **Ireland** for Studies on **Student Visa**. My course is of **one** year.

I want to know, if its permitted to travel **from** Ireland to England on student visa for a short trip. May be few days.

Comment: The Republic of Ireland?

Comment: Your nationality may matter

Comment: As Gagravarr mentioned, your nationality may matter. In 2013 I was allowed to visit Republic of Ireland on a UK Visa as an Indian citizen due to a promotion for the Olympic Games of 2013.

Answer (score 5):

[Ireland have an agreement with the UK](http://www.inis.gov.ie/en/INIS/Visa%20Waiver%20Programme%20Information%20Note%20March%202012.pdf/Files/Visa%20Waiver%20Programme%20Information%20Note%20March%202012.pdf) to allow short term UK visa holders to enter Ireland but from a specific list of countries. However it does not seem it works the other way round for people with Irish visas entering to UK.

Requiring a visa to enter the UK depends on your nationality. You can use the [UK Government website](https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa) to see if you need a visa, it will ask you questions and tell you if you need one.

Answer (score 1):

You would not be entering the UK on an Irish student visa, you would be entering with your original passport and you will require what ever visas your original passport requires.